# What is the equivalent of PDFTextStripper in pdfbox snapshot 2.0

Tags: java, pdf, pdfbox

I am currently using pdfbox 1.8 to analyze PDF documents.  Below is a very stripped down example of what I am doing.

```
 import java.util.List;
 import java.io.IOException;
 import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
 import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument;
 import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDPage;
 import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.common.PDStream;

 public class Main 
 {
   private static PDDocument reader;

   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
       JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
       int result = chooser.showOpenDialog(null);
       if(result == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION)
       {
           try
           {
               reader = PDDocument.load(chooser.getSelectedFile());
               for(int pagenum = 1; pagenum <= reader.getNumberOfPages(); pagenum++)
               {
                   System.out.println("===== Page:" + pagenum + " ======");
                   System.out.println(extract(pagenum));
               }

           }
           catch(Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }

       }
   }

   public static String extract(int pagenum) throws IOException
   {
       List allPages = reader.getDocumentCatalog().getAllPages();
       PDPage page = (PDPage) allPages.get(pagenum-1);
       PDStream contents = page.getContents();
       CustomPDFTextStripper stripper = new CustomPDFTextStripper();        
       if (contents != null) 
       {
           stripper.processStream(page, page.findResources(), page.getContents().getStream());
       }
       return stripper.getContents();
   }
 }
```

and

```
 import org.apache.pdfbox.util.PDFTextStripper;
 import java.io.IOException;
 import org.apache.pdfbox.util.TextPosition;

 public class CustomPDFTextStripper extends PDFTextStripper
 {
   private final StringBuilder builder;
   private float lastBase;
   public CustomPDFTextStripper() throws IOException
   {
       super.setSortByPosition(true);
       builder = new StringBuilder();
       lastBase = Float.MAX_VALUE;
   }

   public String getContents() { return builder.toString(); }

   @Override
   protected void processTextPosition(TextPosition textPos)
   {
       float ascent = textPos.getY();
       if(ascent > lastBase)
           builder.append("\n");
       lastBase = textPos.getY() + textPos.getHeight();
       builder.append(textPos.getCharacter());
       // I want to be able to do stuff here and
       // I need to read spaces and newline characters
   }
 }
```

I can't seem to find an equivalent solution in pdfbox 2.0 snapshot (I know it is unstable and has not been released yet).  I tried to use something like:

```
 CustomPDFTextStripper stripper = new CustomPDFTextStripper();        
 StringWriter dummy = new StringWriter();
 stripper.setPageStart(""+(pagenum-1));
 stripper.setPageEnd(""+(pagenum-1));
 stripper.writeText(reader, dummy);
```

but it does not process spaces or give accurate textPos data in processTextPostion method.

Any ideas of how to get all of the TextPostion data same as 1.8 in 2.0?

========== EDIT 26JUN2015 8:00 PM CST ===========

Ok, I have had some time to look at it and found the problem.  getWidthOfSpace() returns dramatically different result between 1.8 and 2.0.

In 1.8 it is around 2.49 - width of characters are around 5

In 2.0 it is around 27.5 - width of characters are around 5

Obviously 27.5 is wrong in 2.0

just run the following test and you will see

```
 @Override
 protected void processTextPosition(TextPosition textPos)
 {
    float spaceWidth = textPos.getWidthOfSpace();
    float width = textPos.getWidth();
    System.out.println(textPos.getCharacter() + " - Width of Space=" + spaceWidth + " - width=" + width);
    builder.append(textPos.getCharacter());
 }
```

(Of course getUnicode() for 2.0 instead of getCharacter())

===== EDIT 27JUN2015 8:00 PM CST ======

Here is link to PDF in used in test:
[Hello World](https://issues.apache.org/jira/secure/attachment/12742359/Hello%20World.pdf)

Comment: If this works with 1.8 and not with 2.0 (especially with the PrintTextLocations example), then please open an issue with JIRA and attach your PDF.

Comment: It would also be a temporary bug, if you just downloaded today. Try with a revision from 2 days ago. Alternatively, use the current version and revert the last change (rev 1687653) in the file BaseParser.java and build it again. Or watch the comments in PDFBOX-2301, it will likely be fixed this weekend.

Comment: I did not check 2.0 with above code - checked with my complex original code and TextPosition data was wrong.  I will check with above code and follow your suggestions tomorrow evening.

Comment: Please indicate what you mean by *TextPosition data was wrong*. Furthermore, concerning: *I did not check 2.0 with above code* - please supply code that can be used to reproduce the issue.

Comment: Can you share a sample PDF to reproduce that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There indeed is an error in the current calculation of the width of space. `PDFTextStreamEngine.showGlyph(Matrix, PDFont, int, String, Vector)` currently (it's a SNAPSHOT, the situation may differ this evening) calculates the width like this:

```
float horizontalScalingText = getGraphicsState().getTextState().getHorizontalScaling()/100f;
[...]
// the space width has to be transformed into display units
float spaceWidthDisplay = spaceWidthText * fontSizeText * horizontalScalingText *
        textRenderingMatrix.getScalingFactorX()  * ctm.getScalingFactorX();
```

*([PDFTextStreamEngine.java](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/pdfbox/trunk/pdfbox/src/main/java/org/apache/pdfbox/text/PDFTextStreamEngine.java) in revision 1688116)*

but the `textRenderingMatrix` has been calculated in `PDFStreamEngine.showText(byte[])` using:

```
float horizontalScaling = textState.getHorizontalScaling() / 100f;
[...]
Matrix parameters = new Matrix(
        fontSize * horizontalScaling, 0, // 0
        0, fontSize,                     // 0
        0, textState.getRise());         // 1
[...]
Matrix textRenderingMatrix = parameters.multiply(textMatrix).multiply(ctm);
```

*([PDFStreamEngine.java](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/pdfbox/trunk/pdfbox/src/main/java/org/apache/pdfbox/contentstream/PDFStreamEngine.java) in revision 1688116)*

Thus, both the font size and the horizontal scaling are multiplied twice into the space width. Furthermore the current transformation matrix is both fully multiplied into `textRenderingMatrix` and partially used as `ctm.getScalingFactorX()`; this can amount in most interesting combined results.

Most likely it should suffice to remove these values as explicit factors from the `spaceWidthDisplay` calculation in `PDFTextStreamEngine.showGlyph(Matrix, PDFont, int, String, Vector)`

---

In version 1.8.9 the text space width is calculated like this in `PDFStreamEngine.processEncodedText(byte[])`:

```
float spaceWidthDisp = spaceWidthText * fontSizeText * horizontalScalingText 
                        * textMatrix.getXScale() * ctm.getXScale();
```

This can give rise to funny results, too, for interesting current transformation and text matrices but the factors of interest above were not multiplied twice into the result..

Comment: Thanks for the info - I was able to get a correct space width with the following: float spaceWidth = textPos.getFont().getSpaceWidth() * textPos.getTextMatrix().getScaleX() / 1000;  I will mark your answer as the solution and keep an eye on future SNAPSHOTs - Thanks

Comment: * I was able to get a correct space width with the following* - I'm afraid that works only sometimes because it ignores several factors.